# How to specify the argument types of function types

Tags: types, julia

Is there a way in Julia to constrain the argument type of a function type? Let's say I have a function `f = p::Int -> sqrt(p)` and I need to pass this function to other functions, is there a way to specify that these other functions take in functions which themselves take in `Int`, something like `my_func(f::Function{Int}) = ...`.

I am working on a raymarching implementation which uses functions to encode geometry. To combine two geometric objects, I need to take the minimum of their respective functions. Right now, I have this

```
Base.union(f1::Function, f2::Function) = p::Vec -> min(f1(p), f2(p))
```

But using @code_warntype, I see that sometimes it is type-stable while other times it isn't. I think that specifying the argument type of the argument function could help for this.

Related question: when using @code_warntype, what do the #num mean, for example in `var"#226#227"{var"#223#224"{Torus}, var"#219#220"{Sphere}}`?

Comment: Incidentally, since `union` and `Function` belong to Base, you are committing 'type piracy', which is discouraged: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Avoid-type-piracy  It is better if you invent a new name for this operation. It is type piracy if you extend a function you don't 'own' for a type you don't own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer: no, Julia does not have typed functions. But you can achieve type stability without this feature.

the `#num` is just a name given to un-named variables.

Comment: Do you have links to resources where I could learn more about what you talked about, achieving type stability when dealing with anonymous functions and function parameters. Thank!